# The inverse matrix |${\delta}$| does it have an application

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, soft-question

The jacobian is the determinant of |${\delta}$| this means that |${\delta}$| is invertible. Does this inverse have any use in the real world?

Maybe I am not clear in my question:

Does the inverse of a differential matrix have any use in the real world... Physics engineering....ad infinitum

Comment: Are you looking for the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)?

Comment: What do you mean, "this means $|\delta|$ is invertible"?

Comment: @TedShifrin simply that any matrix with a determinant has an inverse.

Comment: Every square matrix has a determinant, but the ones with determinant $0$ have no inverse.

Comment: see edit for clarification